# How to Select Shipping method before start shopping in magento?

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, customer-session

Customer can able to select `shipping method` before to start the shopping experience, I have to place some restriction on shipping method base, Like Shop in 60min with a specific `shipping method` after `60min` if customer didn't able to checkout he will redirect to change shipping method page to choose others options.

What i need to get is list of `shipping method` on a custom page from where customer will choose `shipping method` first & then go to the `product pages` for `add to cart`.

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: The Magento workflow is not done this way: The available shipping methods are shown as result of the entered billing and shipping address. You could maybe prefill/predefine those values incl. setting up a quote to get the shipping methods before continuing to checkout. Keep in mind that there could be some country restrictions on shipping methods (as defined in the backend)